# How can I double unpivot data like in this example in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-science, ssms

I saw sometimes you can use a cross apply, but I feel it won't work in this case as I have 10 columns for "Days" (for 10 years) and 10 columns for "Discharges" (for 10 years).....so I need this pivoted into 10 different row per zip and age group.

Starting output:

| Zipcode | Age | 2022 Days | 2023 Days | 2022 Discharges | 2023 Discharges |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1-10 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 12345 | 11-20 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |

Desired output:

| Zipcode | Age | Year | Days | Discharges |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1-10 | 2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 12345 | 1-10 | 2023 | 3 | 4 |
| 12345 | 11-20 | 2022 | 5 | 6 |
| 12345 | 11-20 | 2022 | 7 | 8 |

The top is essentially what I have (Just only kept 2022 and 2023, but will really be 2022 - 2032).

Is it possible to do two unpivots, a cross apply or something else to achieve this? This is also a realllllllly large dataset (1.5 billion rows), so I'll have to do it in batches, but would rather not do one unpivot, and then another unpivot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample data and desired results are best posted as formatted text

Comment: @JohnCappelletti thanks for the feedback. I have added a table in text.

Answer (score 0):

This will dynamically UNPIVOT your data without having to use Dynamic SQL or having to list the desired columns

**Note:** There will be a price to pay for 1.5 billion rows.

You could use the VALUE approach to UNPIVOT your data, but you would have to specify all the columns up to 2032

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-_heD-eZ)**

```
Select A.Zip_Code
      ,A.Age_Cohort
      ,B.*
From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select [Year]       = try_convert(int,Left([Key],4))
                     ,[Days]       = sum( case when [key] like '%Days%'       then try_convert(int,Value) else 0 end)
                     ,[Discharges] = sum( case when [key] like '%Discharges%' then try_convert(int,Value) else 0 end)
                From  OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                Where [Key] like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_D%'  -- or you can use [Key] not in ('Zip_Code','Age_Cohort')
                Group By Left([Key],4)
             ) B
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JohnCappelletti, after running the whole table, it will be about 16 billion rows. Do you think there would be a better way to store the table? Splitting up the Days and Discharges maybe? Or is this really the best method and best way to store it?

Comment: @manavjn Your desired structure is certainly more usable and easier to analyze.   That said, I have no idea what your USE CASE is.

Comment: @manavjn If you want to test performance just add >>>  WHERE Zip_Code Like '35%'

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot using `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`, this allows you to generate multiple rows from a single outer row.

```sql
SELECT
  t.Zip_Code,
  t.Age_Cohort,
  v.*
FROM @YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (2022, t.[2022_Days], t.[2022_Discharges]),
    (2023, t.[2023_Days], t.[2023_Discharges])
) v(Year, Days, Discharges);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/FIFNGjP_)

Comment: This is likely to be more performant than jsoning it even if you need some c/p